# textfield con mismo nombre en material ui

Tags: reactjs, material

estoy teniendo un problema con react y material ui donde estoy intentando generar varios textfield con un for segun el valor numerico en otro textfield, no habia tenido problema con esto con js vanilla, doy un ejemplo en vanilla hacia esto

```
dt = $("#dt").val();
if (dt == 0 || dt == "" || dt == null || dt == undefined) {
 dt = 1;
}
if (dt > 20) {
 dt = 20;
}
inputDt = "";
inputBu = "";
inputPe = "";
for (let i = 0; i < dt; i++) {
  inputDt += `<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="NÂ° del 
  documento" required="" name="numDt[]" id="numDt">`;
  inputBu += `<input type="number" min="1" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
  placeholder="Cantidad bultos" required="" name="numBul[]" id="numBul" value="1">`;
  inputPe += `<input type='text' id='numPes' name="numPes[]" placeholder="kg" 
  autocomplete="off" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="" value="1"/>`;
}
$("#inputDt").html(inputDt);
$("#inputBu").html(inputBu);
$("#inputPe").html(inputPe);
```

al momento de enviar estos valores en el formulario con el nombre name='numBul[]' no generaba ningun problema, pero en react no me funciona ya que cuando agrego un valor en alguno de los generados todos se me cambian a ese o me sale "[object][object]"

este es el codigo react

```
Array.from({ length: formik.values.cantidadVehiculos }).map((_, index) => (
  <Grid key={index} xs={12} item container spacing={1}>
     <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Autocomplete
           disablePortal
           size="small"
           options={tipoVehiculo}
           onChange={(e, value) => {
             formik.setFieldValue('tipoVehiculo', value?.id || '');
           }}
           onOpen={formik.handleBlur}
           includeInputInList
           renderInput={(p) => (
            <TextField
              {...p}
              id="tipoVehiculo"
              name="tipoVehiculo"
              label="tipoVehiculo"
              error={formik.touched.tipoVehiculo && Boolean(formik.errors.tipoVehiculo)}
              helperText={formik.touched.tipoVehiculo && formik.errors.tipoVehiculo}
            />
           )}
         />
      </Grid>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

usando la libreria Formik logre hacer listas de datos con un componente llamado  por si tienen un problema en la propia pagina de [Ejemplo](https://formik.org/docs/api/field)